# Only one page need to be shown at specific encoding

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8, mojolicious

I have mojolicous app which works in utf-8 encoding.
All my files (templates,code, anything) in utf-8.

But for third-party service I need to show one of my page in win-1251 encoding.

I add new format in startup :

```
$self->types->type(wbm => 'text/html; charset=win-1251');
```

I add template/show/mypage.wbm.ep

```
<%= $txt %>
```

And in my controller I set the format:

```
$self->render( 'show/mypage', format => 'wbm', txt => 'Превед, win1251');
```

And when i visit 127.0.0.1:3000/show/mypage I see right type text/html; charset=win-1251
and wrong characters like

> УУАУЅУЂУЅУЄ, win1251

I tried do encoding in template like:

```
<%=  Encode::encode('windows-1251',$txt) %>
```

And tried do same in controller, but page still shown incorrect.

Help me please.

UPD:

Here is test projects https://github.com/korjavin/MojoWinPage with full code.

Comment: As what encoding does your browser detect the document? The encoding `win1251` does not exists, do you mean `windows-1251`? What is the `$txt` variable supposed to do, where is it populated? You may want to read about the [template language](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Template), and [post-processing hooks](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Rendering#Post-processing_dynamic_content).

Comment: What's the encoding of your source file, and did you use `use utf8;`? I'm guessing the answers are "UTF-8" and "no" (meaning you don't actually have `Превед`), when they should be "UTF-8" and "yes".

Comment: Have you tried to set `$self->renderer->encoding`, see [here](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Rendering#Encoding)?

Comment: @amon Browser with autodetect show me win-1251. Without '-' I use it only once in the string for test.  Thank fo post-processing, I will try.

Comment: @ikegame you right, my answers is UTF-8 and 'no'. But when I add use utf8; in to my controller class file, its change nothing. Still bad  ' РџСЂРµРІРµРґ ' characters in response.

Comment: @SlavenRezic Yes, I do, but its switch encoding for entire app. And its a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by

1. render partial
2. encode it
3. send as raw data

> ```
> my $page = $self->render( 'show/mypage', format => 'wbm', txt => $txt, partial> => 1);
> my $win=Mojo::Util::encode ('cp-1251',$page);
> $self->render(data=>$win);
> ```

Thanks to Sebastian Riedel (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mojolicious/bX_LLQIsop8)